# Should one use first or third person terminology when discussing one's character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is not about viewing the character, but how to refer to them verbally in conversation. On these and other boards I see plenty of people using both first and third person terminology, e.g. "I did this" vs "my character did this"; or "my character prefers magic over weaponry" rather than "I prefer magic over weaponry" in the context of the game. Speaking in the third person makes it seem like the character is an independent entity, which they clearly are not since their existence depends on that of the player.

I find this confusing. Sometimes the player will make the character do things the player would not do in real life in such a situation, but then, *it is still the player making those choices*. My player is female but I am male, I still refer to her as "I" - is this not correct [by "correct" I mean whatever is considered normal practice]?

I am tagging this question with Skyrim, because, unlike with, e.g The Witcher, the player creates the character from the ground up [I am sure there are many other games when the player has to do the same but I don't know what they are].

Comment: This one feels a bit too philosophical and opinion-based for this board. Although an interesting subject, so maybe take to Reddit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "correct" way to do this. Some people like the immersion of character and player and use first-person to reference things that happen in the game. Others like the role-play and want to help themselves differentiate between what they do as a player and what they're making the character do in the game, and so use third-person. You'll find similar behaviors in LARP communities and with tabletop gamers, such as D&D players. It's entirely personal preference.